# Fastest algorithm to print all 16-bit binary numbers in Powershell?

Tags: algorithm, powershell, optimization, binary

The PowerShell should print all 16-bit binary number with leading zeroes like this:

```
0000000000000000
0000000000000001
0000000000000010
0000000000000011
...
1111111111111100
1111111111111101
1111111111111110
1111111111111111
```

My current code looks like this:

```
0 .. 65535 | % { "{0:D16}" -f [int64][convert]::ToString($_,2) }
```

But I am wondering if there are other algorithms that would perform the task faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*tl;dr* The following approach using caching and an array look-up *is* faster, but such may not be realized due to other bottlenecks.

Here is a version which uses caching. However, as per `Measure-Command` there is no significant improvement (3.5 vs 3.8 elapsed seconds) - I was expecting to see a much larger difference.

```powershell
$l = @(0) * 256

0..255 | % {
    $l[$_] = "{0:D8}" -f [int64][convert]::ToString($_,2)
}

0 .. 65535 | % {
    $l[$_ / 256 ] + $l[$_ -band 255]   # no -shr in PS before 3.0
}
```

---

There are two "slow" parts with this problem. One is the use of `%{}` is *slow* compared to a plain loop. Using the above modified to the following (which isn't very useful) completes in 0.3 seconds.

```powershell
For ($i = 0; $i -lt 65535; $i = $i + 1) {
    $line = $l[$i / 256 ] + $l[$i -band 255]
}
```

While a similarly modified, and equally useless, version of the original completes in 0.5 seconds. This *is* a good bit slower than the cached proposed version, even though the proposed approach does not ultimately affect the bottleneck or wall-clock.

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt 65535; $i = $i + 1) {
    $line = "{0:D16}" -f [int64][convert]::ToString($i,2)
}
```

Usefully collecting output manually, with a presized array, is also much faster than `%{}` and it runs in 0.5 seconds for my version - it will run a bit slower for the original approach, say 0.8 seconds.

```
$r = @("") * 65536
# ..
For ($i = 0; $i -lt 65535; $i = $i + 1) {
    $r[$i] = $l[$i / 256 ] + $l[$i -band 255]
}
```

Secondly, actually materializing with `Write-Output` is *very slow* and is slower than collecting the result with `%{}`. Using either `Write-Output` or `Write | Output-File ..` results in times exceeding 8 seconds.

```powershell
$r = @("") * 65536
$l = @(0) * 256

For ($i = 0; $i -lt 256; $i = $i + 1) {
    $l[$i] = "{0:D8}" -f [int64][convert]::ToString($i, 2)
}

For ($i = 0; $i -lt 65535; $i = $i + 1) {
    $r[$i] = $l[$i / 256 ] + $l[$i -band 255]
}

# to here in about 0.5 seconds
Write $r | Out-File results.txt

# almost another 8 seconds to get here
```